# How many types of memory barriers are available in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

For example, in the standards **[C11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order)** and **[C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)**, features **6** types of memory barriers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order

- memory_order_relaxed
- memory_order_consume
- memory_order_acquire
- memory_order_release
- memory_order_acq_rel
- memory_order_seq_cst

Which are determine the directions in which the compiler can reorder instructions, as well as which of processor instructions requires to insert to limit reordering in pipeline of processor.
For example, the first five barriers affect only the compiler , but does not generate any CPU instructions (no `S/L/ MFENCE`), because in x86 - acquire-release-semantics is provided automatically .

How many types of memory barriers available in Java?
Or is there only 2 types?

- All reordering allowed
- All reordering prohibited

Comment: Try informing yourself on the *Roach Motel* model, which covers your question for the most part.

Comment: C++11 has only two barriers, "thread fence" and "signal fence". However, those are configurable with memory ordering parameters.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I mean - memory_order, which can be used in "thread fence", "signal fence" or "atomic variable".

Comment: The Java memory model is part of the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4).

Comment: @Alex "_memory_order, which can be used in "thread fence", "signal fence"_" Only some of these values make sense for fences: only the directions (acq and rel) make sense for a signal fence; in addition, seq_cst makes sense for a thread fence. The others only make sense for an operation on atomic.

Comment: "_For example, the first five barriers affect only the compiler , but does not generate any CPU instructions_" Did you meant your question for Intel only? Can you rewrite that sentence?

Answer (score 5):

There are no explicitly specified "memory barriers" in spec of Java language or its standard libs. There is a Java Memory Model (JMM) which bases on "happens before" relationship. Of course, an implementation of JVM uses some memory barriers to implement JMM, but they are implementaion/hardware specific. See for instance:
http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html
That article defines LoadLoad, LoadStore, StoreLoad, StoreStore abstract memory barriers (non-standard really, but widely used terminology) and describes how they can be implemented on specific hardware.

Comment: Note that the constants listed in the question are not barriers, they are orders.

Comment: Right, the question starts with the orders as an illustration, but it finishes with memory barriers (including another listing S, L, MFENCE) specifically. Barriers are just the way to manage (re)ordering

Comment: The wording of the question is a complete mess. There is mixing of orders, barriers, x86 guarantees... My point is that `memory_order_X` doesn't describe a "barrier".

Comment: "The wording of the question is a complete mess" - formally speaking - yes. But I don't see a problem in understanding what is the question about.